# Stop a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

SharePoint 2013, on Prem environment.  I have a scenario where the client has to complete a form and it kickstarts the workflow for approvals from different stakeholders.  Now there is a requirement that anyone involved in the workflow should be able to cancel the workflow and it needs to send out an email to all involved that the workflow has been canceled.  How will I achieve that and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a OOB workflow or a custom workflow ? For OOB workflow i am not sure if it is feasible.

For custom workflow, there is a stop workflow action in 2010 platform workflow. You can add the action to your approval process for the condition when when a approver reject or other required situation. For 2013 platform workflow, you can add if condition in the transition to stage part. Use a certain stage to just end the workflow. And use if conditions to transit your workflow to an end on required conditions. I hope the description is not too abstract.